# Branching/merging strategy when one of multiple changes is not signed-off

Tags: version-control, branch, cvs

I am trying to come up with a good branching merging strategy for a scenario when multiple features are being tested simultanously and at least one of them is not signed-off by stakeholders. I want to get the signed off changes pushed through to production with the least effort in terms of SCM operations and retesting.

I am using CVS (and I can't change this), but the question is SCM technology agnostic to certain extent.

Imagine that at any given time there are multiple features being developed on a common baseline. They're all worked on in isolation in their own branches. At some stage a build is pushed to test envrionment from the trunk that contains all the finished/tested and merged back to trunk changes. Let's say there are 5 branches merged in total and one is not good enough to pass testing or for some reason is not signed-off by the business.

If there was a silver bullet like 'unmerge' operation it would be perfect, but as far as I know there isn't.

My other idea is not to merge all the changes to trunk but to a separate branch forked off trunk and push a build off that branch to test server. If some change is withdrawn for any reason it would require forking a new branch off trunk and merging all but the withdrawn changes. Once all the changes are accepted this temporary branch can be merged to trunk.

I am wondering if this is not an overkill though.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't really answer your question as asked, you might want to look into the concepts of feature toggles and "branch by abstraction" as discussed in Continuous Delivery.  These are a couple of the core concepts that allow iterative mainline/trunk development.

Comment: This is very informative. Thanks! The thing is that most of projects we're dealing with are web applications and many feature/work requests involve markup changes. I can't think of any way of creating abstraction layers over markup/css/js and so on.

Comment: artur, the alternative are "feature switches" in the form of ugly TEMPORARY "if" statements that test against a config value.  Trust me, I know how ugly this sounds.  The key is recognizing it as a temporary measure and making CERTAIN that you remove these blights to your codebase ASAP.